# Vuetify combobox Value Set up

Tags: combobox, vuetify.js

I used vuetify v-select but just change to v-combobox. There is a problem with value. For the v-select it was

```
[{
"text":"(NEC (1)) NEC work orders",
"value":"26729191407887178"
}]
```

After i changed to v-combobox it will show "26729191407887178". Is that possible to show `(NEC (1)) NEC work orders` in v-combobox?

```
<v-combobox
    v-model="pwra.pwra_code"
    label="Pwra Code"
    :items="pwraCodeList"
    dense
    outlined
    :hide-details="true"
    :rules="[rules.required]"
></v-combobox>
```

Comment: `v-combobox` is just a component that extends `v-select`, so it should work with data same way. Could you post whole component or create a reproducible example on CodePen?

Comment: Which `vuetify` version are you using? Vue 2.6.11 and vuetify 2.3.10 seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `return-object` of `<v-combobox/>` to `false` then make a computed variable (in this example, its `pwraCode`) that finds the code in the `pwraCodeList` array and return it. If it isn't found, just return the typed input string.

```html
<v-combobox
  ... 
  v-model="pwraCode"
  :return-object="false"
>
</v-combobox>
```

```js
// script

data: () => ({
  pwra: {
    pwra_code: "26729191407887178"
  },
  pwraCodeList: [...]
}),

computed: {
  pwraCode: {
    get: function() {
      // find the code if it exist, else, just return the typed input
      const code = this.pwraCodeList.find(
        code => code.value === this.pwra.pwra_code
      );
      return code || this.pwra.pwra_code;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      this.pwra.pwra_code = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a demo at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-ptolemy-7900g?file=/src/components/Playground.vue):

[image]

Comment: Great Thanks! That's what I want!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use the `item-text` prop. Just point it to the text key.

```
<v-combobox
    v-model="pwra.pwra_code"
    label="Pwra Code"
    :items="pwraCodeList"
    item-text="text"
    dense
    outlined
    :hide-details="true"
    :rules="[rules.required]"
></v-combobox>
```

And what dreamwalker said is true - it's just an extended v-select.

Comment: I believe `item-value` will not work with v-combobox at the moment. See the docs [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/#api). It says *"Note: This is currently not supported with v-combobox"*

Comment: @Blackraspberryyy Thanks you're right the combobox returns only an object.